# Getting Error in playing .mp4 video format in Android Programming?

Tags: android

I have added .mp4 file in RAW folder after converting from .wmv format. I have added that at startup of my application.But In Emulator its showing "SORRY,this video cannot be played."

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MP4 is a container format, so if the Video can be played or not depends on the Video-codec that is used.

You should check if your codec is supported by Android and if not use another one.